# Mac App Store Xcode 5 deletes Xcode 4

Tags: xcode, xcode4, ios7, xcode5

Just installed Xcode 5 with the app store, since iOS 7.0.2 released.

I had a renamed version of Xcode 4 in my applications folder, which was deleted (I assume) during the installation process of Xcode 5, even though I had renamed the package to Xcode_4_iOS6.app.

Had the GM seed version of Xcode 5 living beside quite happily beforehand.

It's not in my trash folder. And what is the best way of having both versions at the same time? I don't want to have to restore from backup every time a new is released!

Comment: in your application folder keep Xcode 5 and create a new folder with Xcode 4 inside

Comment: what difference is that to renaming the Xcode.app package?

Comment: Don't know but it doesn't work for me when I renamed the Xcode.app but work when I create a separate folder.

Comment: maybe for same reason as mttrb answer bellow - maybe App store only searches for receipt in 1st level.

Comment: Do you have access to the Apple Developer Downloads website?  If so installing from there avoids this issue as you manage the installation of the app bundles yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that the Mac App Store finds the old Xcode by searching for the App Store receipt file.

Some people have reported (on Twitter) successfully keeping Xcode 4 by deleting the receipt file in `Xcode.app/Contents/_MASReceipt/receipt` before installing Xcode 5 (probably best to just delete the `_MASReceipt` directory). Obviously you also need to rename the old `Xcode.app`.